# selenium execute_script gives error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to execute the javascript function of webpage using the selenium package of python

I would like to click on row value

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="cursor:hand" 
      onmouseover="onmouseoverTR(this)" 
      onmouseout="onmouseoutTR(this)"         
      onclick="clearwsInfo('2015011800017','2015011800017',this);"
      ondblclick='doSelect("auditflowForm","2015011800017");'>
```

function as

```
function  clearwsInfo(tmpdjbh,tmpsgbh,obj)
{  
    //判断yesnot existentTR已被existent，如果yes就还原到原来的样式
    if ( obj !=""  && obj !=null  )
    {  
        if(preTR!=""){

            preTR.style.background='#FFFFFF';

        }   

        obj.style.background='#c9e3ef';

        preTR=obj;
    }

     var forms = "parent.document." + gFormName + ".";

     parent.document.getElementById("tmpsgbh").value = tmpsgbh;    
     parent.document.getElementById("tmpdjbh").value = tmpdjbh;   

     loadDwr(tmpdjbh,tmpsgbh) ; 

     parent.document.wsList.location.href = "http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/wsTreeAction.do?cs=1&sgbh="+ tmpsgbh;
}
```

code which I tried is

```
iedriver = 'C:\Users\IEDriverServer.exe'
browser = webdriver.Ie(iedriver)
browser.get   ('http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/LookAuditflowListAction.do')
browser.execute_script("clearwsInfo('2015011800017','2015011800017',this)")
```

I got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\surendra\Neon-WorkSpace\EvidenseData\selinum.py", line 25, in   <module>
  browser.execute_script("clearwsInfo ('2015011800017','2015011800017',this)")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site- packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 465, in execute_script
  'args': converted_args})['value']
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site- packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
  self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-   packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: JavaScript error
```

how can I execute the function clearwsInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just simply click on the TR element, and let the JavaScript do the rest, like an human interaction.

```
iedriver = 'C:\Users\IEDriverServer.exe'
browser = webdriver.Ie(iedriver)
browser.get   ('http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/LookAuditflowListAction.do')
tr = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='font9']//tr[contains(@onclick, 'clearws')]")
tr.click()
```

Comment: I tried                                                                                                         tr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/TABLE/tr')  for hierarchy

Comment: <body bottomMargin=0 leftMargin=0 topMargin=0 >
  <TABLE  border="1"  bordercolorlight="#6D6D6D" cellspacing="1"
        class=font9  #4D5E8C 1px solid" >
   <tr  bgcolor="#CCCCCC"     >       
    <td  class="title_1" width ='6%' align="center">case number</td>  
    <td  class="title_1" width ='10%' align="center">time of accident</td>    
   </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="cursor:hand"              
       onclick="clearwsInfo('2015011800017','2015011800017',this);"
       ondblclick='doSelect("auditflowForm","2015011800017");'>

Comment: <body bottomMargin=0 leftMargin=0 topMargin=0 >
      <TABLE  border="1"  bordercolorlight="#6D6D6D" cellspacing="1"
        class=font9  #4D5E8C 1px solid" >
   <tr  bgcolor="#CCCCCC"     >       
    <td  class="title_1" width ='6%' align="center">case number</td>  
    <td  class="title_1" width ='10%' align="center">time of accident</td>    
   </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="cursor:hand"              
       onclick="clearwsInfo('2015011800017','2015011800017',this);"
       ondblclick='doSelect("auditflowForm","2015011800017");'>

Comment: i got the error                                                                                        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with xpath == //html/body/TABLE/tr

Comment: Test this xpath: //table[@class='font9']//tr[contains(@onclick, 'clearws')]